# Decodificar URL recebida

Tags: php, api, url, pagamento-online

Estou trabalhando em integração de pagamentos através do Pagar.me, porém não estou conseguindo decodificar o postback deles para realizar o tratamento das informações retornadas.

O formato de retorno é em base de URL, realizei um `url_decode()` para tratar melhor as informações, no final ele fica assim:

```
id=000000&fingerprint=0000000000&event=transaction_status_changed&old_status=processing&desired_status=paid&current_status=refused&object=transaction&transaction[object]=transaction....
```

Meu problema é em conseguir usar essas informações para realizar a validação necessária, eu precisaria pegar a informação do campo `fingerprint` e alguns outros, porém não estou conseguindo como posso realizar essa ação.

Pensei em tentar fazer um array ou algo nesse estilo, mas não tive muito sucesso.

Espero que consigam me ajudar.

Comment: Já tentou a [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php)?

Comment: @Woss, ainda não, vou pesquisar a doc pra usar ela e ver se consigo. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: @Woss, deu certo, consegui manipular. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tente usar o parse_str.
Exemplo

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda João, estava mexendo com a dica do Woss que era o `parse_str` também e deu certo. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.